# How to query at low level using SQLite.Net-PCL?

Tags: c#, uwp, sqlite-net

I am using SQLite.Net-PCL in a UWP project. Now, I need to read one row of a table. 
I could use something like:

```
var row = await _conn.QueryAsync<MyType>("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=100");
```

The problem is that the table has 150 columns and I do not want to write a class (MyType) just for this query. I would like to load all columns in a `Dictionary<string, string>` or similar, so I could get the values I need.

How can I do it using the SQLite.Net-PCL wrapper?

**UPDATE:**

The column names that I need to retrieve are only known in runtime, so I cannot create a class.
The final purpose is to show a dashboard. The user can select 6 columns from a list of 150. Then, I want to show only these 6 columns in the view.

Comment: if the field names are defined by user in runtime, you need to save those field names in a separate table and then build your select statement around it. When Column Names are integral part of the program, you need to make sure they are also saved/retrieved. `When the user picks from a list which columns he/she wants to see in the view.` save their preferences and you should be good.

Comment: Downvote? Really? Can the Person who downvoted my comment explain why?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, may you explain here? Thanks.